# Category Template - to be editable from the backend?

Tags: categories, metabox, templates

I have different categories that includes posts of the category. I want to add text and images before or after the posts of the categories are displayed on the frontend. I want to solve this via custom meta fields, but therefore the template of each category needs to be editable from the wordpress backend.

Is this possible? Or need I to create a "Before Category XYZ"-Page which will be included on the category template?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I used [this plugin](http://magnigenie.com/product/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-category-pages/) and it does the job. Now I can design my category pages from my admin backend using my page builder.